# Can i host just ms access database and access it from a desktop software and also from android?

Tags: ms-access

I created a simple desktop software with ms access as backend, now i want to host it  and wanna connect three computer which are having my software and also a android app with that database?
So is it possible to do that or should i change my database?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: ODBC should work. It won't be pretty.I'd look at a client-server architecture rather than Access.